# How to expand Search to full lenght and not show other icons?

Tags: android

I have a search button in a fragment, but there is also another icon in the actionbar. If I press search then the other icon is still shown :/

I have tried some other solutions posted here but none of them seem to work for a fragment.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView)menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

Doesn't work at all

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />
```

I think this is the right approach as it then displays a back arrow and i can cancel the search by pressing back. But my other icons are still there, they are just placed to the right side. The app crashed if I type something and anther button is pressed.

This doesn't get called at all:

```
  MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem).addOnAttachStateChangeListener(new View.OnAttachStateChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View arg0) {
                // search was detached/closed
            }

            @Override
            public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View arg0) {
                // search was opened
            }
        });
```

Here only the onClose listener is never called:

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Hide other option item
                if (menu != null) {
                    menu.findItem(R.id.action_sort).setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        });

        searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onClose() {
                // Show other option item
                if (menu != null) {
                    menu.findItem(R.id.action_sort).setVisible(true);
                    return true;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Post your code what have you tried so far?

Comment: Done! The second thing actually works a lot better but I still can't keep the other buttons. They take up too much space and crash if I press them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `show/hide` other `option` item programmatically by using `searchClick` and `close` listener.

**To do this, update your `onCreateOptionsMenu` as below:**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();

    searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Hide other option item
            if (menu != null) {
                 menu.findItem(R.id.action_other).setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    });

    searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            // Show other option item
            if (menu != null) {
                menu.findItem(R.id.action_other).setVisible(true);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```

**Ofcourse,** you should use attribue `app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"` to your `action_search` item in `menu_search.xml`

**menu_search.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_other"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_other"
        android:title="Other"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

**UPDATE:**

Try using `MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener()`:

```
MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(menuItem, new OnActionExpandListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
        // Do something when collapsed
        return true;  // Return true to collapse action view
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
        // Do something when expanded
        return true;  // Return true to expand action view
    }
});
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: Great that works! Could you explain what happens if I return true of false in the onClose function?

Comment: Return true if you want to override the default behavior of clearing the text field and dismissing it, false otherwise. See documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.OnCloseListener.html

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, but I just noticed that the icon doesn't reappear. I have updated my Question.

Comment: Put some log inside onClose() method to know weather its called or not. As i told before, try to return false from onClose. public boolean onClose() {
                // Show other option item
                if (menu != null) {
                    menu.findItem(R.id.action_sort).setVisible(true);
                }
                return false;
            }

Comment: I have tried loging and debuging  and I am quite certain that it is not called. The Listener is set as soon as I launch the app but the onClose functino itself isn't called.

Comment: Try using `MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener()`. check my updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142404/discussion-between-newtoeverything-and-ferdous-ahamed).